# How to select the word from two associated lines?

Tags: linux

I want to select the word form associated two lines. For example, below two lines will always appear together line by line. And the number 87 may change. I want to select the word/number 87, how to use sed or awk to do so?

```
string "abc"
var    int 87
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/^string \"/ { getline ; print $3; }'
```

This says to match `string "` at the beginning of the line.  Then get the next line and print the third word.

For example:

```
$ cat junk.txt
string "abc"
var int  87
some other thing
string "qwerty"
var int 99
$ cat junk.txt | awk '/^string \"/ { getline ; print $3; }'
87
99
$
```